# How to translate in Django in a right way

Tags: django

I'm tying to send an email in two languages using django.

In my settings.py I have it as follows:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

And my project tree is as follows:

[image]

The code for sending email is as follows:

```
to_email = [email, ]
from_email = 'no-reply@company.com'
to_cc_emails = download_documents_cc_emails
subject = _('The requested document')
html_content = render_to_string('email_templates/download_documents.html', {'name': name})

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, html_content, from_email, to_email, to_cc_emails)
msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
msg.attach_file(file_to_be_sent)
msg.send()
```

And `download_documents.html` is as follows:

```
{% load i18n %}
<div>
    <div>{% trans "Dear" %} {{ name|capfirst }},</div>
    <div style="margin: 25px 0;">
        {% trans "The requested document is attached." %} <br />
    </div>
    <div>{% trans "Best regards" %}</div>
</div>
```

When I do `django-admin makemessages -l nl` inside locale folder the right labels are created:

```
#: main/views.py:68
msgid "The requested document"
msgstr "Het aangevraagde document"

#: templates/email_templates/download_documents.html:3
msgid "Dear"
msgstr "Geachte"

#: templates/email_templates/download_documents.html:5
msgid "The requested document is attached."
msgstr "In bijlage vindt u het document."

#: templates/email_templates/download_documents.html:7
msgid "Best regards"
msgstr "Met vriendelijke groeten,"
```

But when I get the email it isn't translated. I get the email in English.

Any idea what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to activate target language before rendering email template?

```
from django.utils import translation
translation.activate("nl")
...
render_to_string(...)
```